# SLF 4j Logs are not written to log

Tags: java, log4j, slf4j

Logs are not written properly

slf version slf4j-api-1.7.5.jar, slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar, log4j-1.2.16.jar

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">
<!-- log4j generic catchall for adapters. -->
<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">
<!-- Example DailyRollingFile appender, this is the preferred logging appender -->

    <appender name="CommonAdapterAppender" class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender">
      <param name="file" value="/opt/adapter.log" />
      <param name="encoding" value="UTF-8" />
      <param name="append" value="true" />
      <!-- Rollover at the top of every hour -->
      <param name="DatePattern" value="'.'yyyy-MM-dd-HH" />
      <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern"
          value="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS-zzz} %5p [%t] %c{1} - %m%n" />
      </layout>
    </appender>

    <!-- Categories -->
    <category name="com.other" additivity="false">
      <priority value="warn" />
    </category>

    <logger name="com.adapter" additivity="false">
        <level value="debug" />
        <appender-ref ref="CommonAdapterAppender"/>
    </logger>
    <logger name="com.adaptations" additivity="false">
        <level value="debug" />
        <appender-ref ref="CommonAdapterAppender"/>
    </logger>

    <root>
        <priority value="error" />
        <appender-ref ref="CommonAdapterAppender" />
        <!-- <appender-ref ref="SyslogAppender"/> -->
    </root>
</log4j:configuration>
```

The above log4j file is used by multiple adapters. First time it is writing to adapter.log and after that only some component logs are written. Also I have noticed that after the second time it is writing few logs to adapter.log..

I cannot understand what is going wrong here. Can someone please help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you should be using a single shared log 4J configuration and instance for all your adapters if you want to use the the same log file.

As is, Log 4j instances are probably competing for the control of the file.

Comment: These "adapters" are deployed within an application server or servlet container ?

Comment: Those are stand alone adapters with individual JVM's

Comment: Then I would not use the same log file for all your adapters or write your own appender, making sure it does proper file locking, appending, etc...

Comment: I am trying to resolve this problem using socket appender. Should that work ?